# passing checkbox & text field value in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a text value field over to the next page for every checkbox selected, but I'm only getting the last text fields value, example:

```
checkbox textfield
selected ABCD
selected ABCDE
```

**I am only getting back the ABCDE every time**

**page1.php**

```
echo "<td width='10px'><input name='question[$rowid][]' type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>";
echo "<td width='230px'><input name='newname' type='text' value='$certn'/></td>";
```

**page2.php**

```
foreach ($_POST['question'] as $key => $ans) {
$nn = $_POST['newname'];
echo $key . $nn;
echo "</br>";
}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to work out exactly what you're doing here but I think your statement `I'm only getting the last text fields value` indicates your problem - you have multiple fields with the same name. If you do this and don't make them into an array (`[]`), you will only get the last value on the page.

I think you want something more like this:

*Page 1:*

```
echo "<td width='10px'><input name='question[$rowid]' type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>";
echo "<td width='230px'><input name='newname[$rowid]' type='text' value='$certn'/></td>";
```

*Page 2:*

```
foreach ($_POST['question'] as $key => $ans) {
  // $_POST['newname'] is now also an array, and the keys should correspond to
  // those in the $_POST['question'] array
  $nn = $_POST['newname'][$key];
  echo $key . $nn;
  echo "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
echo "<td width='10px'><input name='question[$rowid][]' type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>";
```

will not be correctly interpreted. You must change it to:

```
echo "<td width='10px'><input name='" . $question[$rowid][] . "' type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>";
```

Arrays are not substitued inside a string.

Comment: First, yes they are under certain circumstances (and the above would be one), second he is naming the HTML field not putting a PHP value in it and third, even if he was putting a value in it, the `[]` means an implicit array push, which is an assignment operation and makes no sense for it to be used in a concatenation, it is only the left side of an expression.